# RabbitMQ message grouping/ordering

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I'm sending some messages to RabbitMQ, currently to `com.products` queue, then consuming them with `Pika` (Python Module). Everything works great, with some threading stuff to make it faster.

But I want to get when some kind of products are being consumed, let's say by `category`, theese are some sample messages

```
{"id": 1, "product": 00039, "category": "1"}
{"id": 2, "product": 00132, "category": "2"}
{"id": 3, "product": 00099, "category": "3"}
{"id": 4, "product": 00123, "category": "1"}
{"id": 5, "product": 00001, "category": "1"}
```

I start consuming, from `com.products` but I want to know when a `category` doesn't has any item left.

Maybe an option can be using a queue for each category, but that way I can't consume with a multithread python script, because it connects to one queue per thread (the same queue)

I don't know how to achieve this at this time, and as  far as I've read, there's no possible way to handle this behaviour.

Comment: in the case when you would have one queue per category, is there a reason to not having multiple consumers per queue there as well?

Comment: That's the way I'm doing right now. Each consumer is consuming only its category and rejecting the others (requeueing them)

Comment: if you have one queue per category, and do message routing based on the category, then let's say queue_cat_1 will only receive messages for that category. You could then attach more than one consumer per queue, which will let you paralellise work. You can also query the queue to know if it's empty